# Is it possible to aggregate data.table using column number and not column names in large dataset?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate a data.table. To be more precise, i have a data.table with 202 column, i want to `aggregate(dt[,131:202]~dt[,1:130],data=dt,FUN=sum)`. 
Here is a data.table so you can try to do it.

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,4,6,4)
B <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
C <- c(10,11,23,8,8,1,3)
D <- c(2,3,5,9,7,8,4)
E <- c(2,5,7,1,4,6,15)
G <- c("b","f","s","k","t","r","n")
H <- c(2,68,5,27,11,17,4)


dt <- data.table(A,B,C,D,E,G,H)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did not work? Try to show some effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data.table option would be to specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, grouping columns in `by`, loop over the `.SD` (Subset of data.table) and get the `sum`

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = c(names(dt)[1:130]), .SDcols = 131:202]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:7], 130*20, replace = TRUE),
        20, 130), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 130*20, replace = TRUE), 20, 
       130), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dt <- data.table(d1, d2)
names(dt) <- make.unique(names(dt))
```

Comment: Do you think that i can in also do a paste in the same line ? i mean i want to paste a column, let's say that it's the 5th column.

Comment: Finally, it doesn't work, i don't know why but the agrgegate is ok  but not the sum :/

Comment: @OrhanYazar  On a test dataset I tried, it is working.  You may need to check the `str` whether the columns are `numeric` class or not.  If it is not numeric, it will not work

Comment: how can i precise that collapse = ";" in the paste so ?

Comment: `dt[, lapply(.SD, sum,.SD2, paste(,collapse=";")), by = c(names(dt)[c(1:130)]), .SDcols = 131:202, .SD2cols=5]` i'm looking for something like that

Comment: @OrhanYazar  You cannot have two sets of `.SDcols`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150916/discussion-between-orhan-yazar-and-akrun).

Comment: @OrhanYazar  ONe option is `dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, 131:202, with = FALSE], sum), lapply(.SD[, 1:130, with = FALSE], toString))]`

Comment: @OrhanYazar  If we need to group, then `dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, 131:202, with = FALSE], sum), lapply(.SD[, 5:130, with = FALSE], toString)), by = c(names(dt)[1:4])]`

Comment: Ok, First, the sum is ok now, i apologize i had a litle problem. and then, i already tried wiith a toString but it separate by "," and with a space i would like to separate by ";" without space :/ But anyway i found i way to do it with 2 lines using yours at second thank you very much

Comment: @OrhanYazar The `toString` is `paste(..., collapse=", ")` You can replace it with `paste, collapse=";"`